# Timing accuracy in React

Tags: reactjs, timing

I am considering using React to run behavioural studies on the web. Such studies require knowing exactly when elements such as images are displayed on screen, and being able to accurately specify the duration they are shown (eg via requestAnimationFrame).

I would love to use React but I worry that it is not fit for my purpose given this from the official documentation:

> There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may be batched for performance gains ([source](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate))

I appreciate your advice.

Comment: You want to use ReactJS for building a site, that will inspect various behaviors? For example react site which will display images, and in addition you want to measure duration of the displayed element?

Comment: Here's an example of a study. An image is shown on screen for 50 ticks (frames). The User must press Space if it was an image of a face. I need to know that the image was indeed shown for 50 ticks (and the time it took the person to click the button, but that is another matter).